# using webclient to download data from url into a div

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url

im trying to get data from another url and post it into a div in my page.
but i run into unexpected runtime error.

in the getSource method, when i write the localhost page as url, i get the error.
is the url writing wrong?

```
Protected Sub populate()
  litComment.Text = getSource("http://localhost:3395/CGH%20Proj/AntibioticRecordManagement.aspx") 'http://localhost:3395/CGH%20Proj/Comments.aspx")

End Sub

Protected Function getSource(ByVal url As String) As String
    Dim r As String = ""
    Using wc As WebClient = New WebClient()
        r = wc.DownloadString(url)
        Return r
    End Using

End Function
```

Comment: It seems OK to me. You need to verify the URL - resource file and path.

Comment: what do you mean by verifying? example?